# Can we convert RSA private key in PKCS1 format to PKCS8 using java code and native libraries?

Tags: java

I want to use PKCS1 format pem file to sign an API request. Java has library that can use key file in PKCS8 format but not in PKCS1. How can we convert PKCS1 to PKCS8 using java (without Bountycastle)?